# Excel sum index match date criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

Daily Data table (extract) (current size: rows 500 columns 1500)

| Emp | 27/10/19 | 28/10/19 | 29/10/19 | 30/10/19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 5.0 | 7.0 | 7.0 | 7.0 |
| 234567 | 6.0 | 8.0 | 8.0 | 8.0 |

Weekly Summary table (extract)

| Emp | 27/10-02/11/19 | 03/11-09/11/19 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | ??? | ??? |
| 234567 | ??? | ??? |

These are structured table on different worksheet within the same workbook.  Any formula to use in ??? to calculate sum of 7 days as described in the header cell?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the formula solution

In "Weekly Summary Table" `B8`, formula copied right to `C8` and all copied down :

1] Using **SUMIFS** function

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($2:$3,MATCH($A8,$A$2:$A$3,0),0),$1:$1,">="&REPLACE(B$7,6,6,""),$1:$1,"<="&RIGHT(B$7,8))
```

Or,

2] Using **SUM+OFFSET** function

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($A8,$A$2:$A$3,0),MATCH(0+REPLACE(B$7,6,6,""),$1:$1,0)-1,1,7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the SUMIFS option. It works if my Daily Data Table is in "range" format. However when I turn it into a structured table, the date format of the header cells are converted into text format, which means the SUMIFS criteria cant be met.

Comment: SUM+OFFSET option seems working fine when I remove the "0+" in the MATCH function as it matches two text formatted "date".